# C# SQLCommand adding parameters return 'Invalid object name '@table'

Tags: c#, sql

I'm working on a C# DB project and I keep getting this error when I try to add parameters to the command text.

> 'Invalid object name '@table'.'

This error appears for every parameter I add.

```cs
sqlcmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [@table](@iVar, @uVar, @pVar) VALUES (@vali, @val1, @val2)";

sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@table", "Data");
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iVar", "Var1");
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uVar", "Var2");
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pVar", "Var3");
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vali", "Val1");
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", "Val2");
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", "Val3");

sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: You can not pass the table name as parameter to query. Parameters are used for passing values to the command not the table name or column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table names & column names cannot be passed as a parameter to SQL command. You can, however, use the below.

```
var tableName = "Data";
var iVar = "Var1";
var uVar = "Var2";
var pVar = "Var3";
sqlcmd.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO [{tableName}]({iVar}, {uVar}, {pVar}) VALUES (@vali, @val1, @val2)";

sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vali", "Val1");
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", "Val2");
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", "Val3");

sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Note that `$` is used for [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

You will then have to ensure that `tableName`, `iVar`, `uVar` and `pVar` is **whitelisted** to avoid any kind of SQL injection attacks if you are taking this value from end-user.

Answer (score 0):

Tables names need to be static.  If you are getting the table name from some form of user input you need to validate it.  You can do something like the following using a stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT * from tablename'
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

or something like

```
SELECT @sSQL = N'SELECT * FROM' + QUOTENAME(@TableName);
EXEC sp_executesql @sSQL
```